# Visual studio crashes then restarts ONCE every first launch of the day

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crash, restart

I am using visual studio 2015 and every time i open it for the first time after my pc has been off during the night it crashes then restarts the client. It only crashes/restarts after i open ANY solution/project

So to be clear it only crashes and restarts when it is the very first launch of the day. Otherwise it works perfectly fine. It doesn't bother me that much just wondering why.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was clearing out the app cache.  The cache location is:

%AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache